# Create database role to allow read access to all tables; write access to some

Tags: sql-server-2012, security, role

We have a database with over 1000 tables. I need to create a role that allows read only on all tables, as well as write access to two specific tables.

I was messing around with database roles, but whenever I went to add the tables, I had to hand select all 1000... is there a better way to do this?

Comment: That actually might be the simplest way... Is there a way to script that? I need to keep a set of scripts for whenever we refresh one of these databases, I can get all setting back instantly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Granting permissions on the schema (e.g. `dbo`) will cascade to all the objects in that schema. For individual exceptions you can just list those explicitly:

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [role];
GO

GRANT INSERT, UPDATE --, DELETE
  ON dbo.table_they_can_write_to TO [role];

DENY SELECT ON dbo.table_they_cannot_read TO [role];
```

Comment: Easy enough. Glad we have a community like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON ? to [ROLE]'
```

Comment: FYI this gives write but no read access to all the tables, and also ignores schema altogether. Also `sp_MSForEachTable` is undocumented, unsupported, and possibly suffers [the same skipping issues as `sp_MSForEachDB`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/).